# How to add texts or label to an object like decals?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In this site：https://www.owayo.com/konfigurator_html/index.php?sport=basketball&product=shirts&lang=en&land=us#

You can put button "Text", then add text and put button "Ok".
The text you created add to objects like a decal.

How can I display this effect?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create a texture from text and add it to the material